# Attach files with the contact form Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contacts

I want people to attach files with the form (Wordpress). But its not working for me.

http://ashad.info/hhh/contact/

This is the wordpress contact code

`
    Contact us

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name1">Your Full Name*:</label>
           [text* text id:Name1 class:form-control]
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Email1">Email Address*</label>
            [email* email id:Email2 class:form-control]
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Email1">Message:</label>
           [textarea* textarea class:form-control]
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
<label for="InputFile">Your file: (If its more than 2mb please email)</label>
```

[file your-file filetypes:zip|pdf|jpg|zip|rar|png id:InputFile limit:2mb]

```
  </div>

  <div class="submit_btn">
           [submit class:submit_b "Submit"]
  </div>
```

`

Comment: can u pls elaborate .. whether it is not send in the mail or file are not uploaded

Comment: It doesn't send the message or send the file gives an error like this "Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the administrator by another method."

Comment: Please check the settings at backend in contact form 7 .. its not fully done of the live server that's why printing this error

Answer (score 0):

If you use Contact form 7, in File attachments area you should add [your-file].